# Delete record using linQ with lambda Expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I want to delete records of sql database using linq lambda expression. What should I do?

Here 'student' is my table and 'db' is object of .edmx file

```
public bool DeleteRecord(int caurseID)
{
    studentEntities db = new studentEntities();

    int count = db.student.Where(s => s.caurse_id == caurseID).Count();

    if (count != 0)
    {
        //string subQuery = "delete from student where caurse_id=" + caurseID;
        //SqlCommand subCmd = new SqlCommand(subQuery, conn);
        //subCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        db.student. : For Delete, what will be goes here???
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got reference from previous suggestion.

```
studentEntities db_dlt = new studentEntities();
                var students = db_dlt.student.FirstOrDefault(s => s.caurse_id == caurseID);
                if (students != null)
                {
                    db_dlt.student.Remove(students);
                    db_dlt.SaveChanges();
                }
```

Comment: That removes exactly **zero or one** student. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Right, I am using while loop to delete multiple records.

Comment: That will generate two queries and two roundtrips to the database *per student*. That's a lot of unnecessary roundtrips but if you're happy with that, and it works, knock yourself out.

Answer (score 2):

```
public bool DeleteRecord(int caurseID)
{
   studentEntities db = new studentEntities();

   var students = db.student.Where(s => s.caurse_id == caurseID);


   if(students.Any()) 
   {
       db.DeleteAllOnSubmit(students);

       db.SubmitChanges();
   }

   return true;
}
```

Comment: One very important thing to point out here, since it's just code - this will generate **two** separate database roundtrips: one to find the entities to delete, and one to issue the delete commands. The roundtrip to delete the entities will issue *one delete statement per entity*, not a single delete-statement.

Comment: Code is not EntityFramework (but Linq2SqlServer or something similar (LinqPad))

Comment: @J.Steen how to delete it in a single round trip